# glVertexAttrib*: which attribute indices are predefined?

Tags: opengl

the glVertexAttrib family of functions allows to add generic attributes to each vertex.
You can set a index that the data will be associated with. However, you can't choose the index arbitrarily, since I discovered that using indices lower than 4 will break standard (Normal/TexCoord) attributes, plus 0 is the vertex position.
How can I find out, which will be the first real free index to use for custom attributes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't be choosing your own indices. GL can provide free ones for you through the [glGetAttribLocation](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glGetAttribLocation.xml) function by using the attribute name in code (if you do this after linking the program).

I never encountered this problem... but unfortunately I don't have my own shader wrapper code to hand (at work atm) to be able to explain why.

Comment: This is not true, the OpenGL specification allows to arbitrarily choose indexes. There is however an issue with NVidia, see heeen's answer.

Comment: By the way, see this answer for a very good reason to choose your own indices: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4638906/253883

Answer (score 7):

I found a website which lists the predefined indices on nvidia hardware:

http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/tutorials/ClockworkCoders/attributes.php

> Unfortunately there are certain
>   limitations when using this on NVidia
>   Hardware. According to NVidia: "GLSL
>   attempts to eliminate aliasing of
>   vertex attributes but this is integral
>   to NVIDIA’s hardware approach and
>   necessary for maintaining
>   compatibility with existing OpenGL
>   applications that NVIDIA customers
>   rely on. NVIDIA’s GLSL implementation
>   therefore does not allow built-in
>   vertex attributes to collide with a
>   generic vertex attributes that is
>   assigned to a particular vertex
>   attribute index with
>   glBindAttribLocation. For example, you
>   should not use gl_Normal (a built-in
>   vertex attribute) and also use
>   glBindAttribLocation to bind a generic
>   vertex attribute named "whatever" to
>   vertex attribute index 2 because
>   gl_Normal aliases to index 2."
>
> In other words, NVidia hardware
>    indices are reserved for built-in
>    attributes:

- gl_Vertex    0
- gl_Normal    2
- gl_Color 3
- gl_SecondaryColor    4
- gl_FogCoord      5
- gl_MultiTexCoord0    8
- gl_MultiTexCoord1    9
- gl_MultiTexCoord2     10
- gl_MultiTexCoord3    11
- gl_MultiTexCoord4    12
- gl_MultiTexCoord5    13
- gl_MultiTexCoord6    14
- gl_MultiTexCoord7    15

Comment: For further reference, note that these are the same indices indicated in the ARB_vertex_program specification.  The missing indices in your list are (1:) blend weights 0-3,  (6:) point size, and (7:) blend indices.  6 is used for point sprites and 1 and 7 are used for hardware skinning.

Answer (score 2):

You can actually use vertex attribute arrays exclusively and thus skip `glVertexPointer()` and co entirely. This will avoid any double ups and is also nicely unified. You should still use `glGetAttribLocation()` though, because AFAIK you can't know ahead of time what index each attribute will be mapped to at runtime.

As always, [the extension spec](http://oss.sgi.com/projects/ogl-sample/registry/ARB/vertex_shader.txt) has all the gory details.