# What is the purpose of using glBindAttributeLocation in GLSL?

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Explicit vs Automatic attribute location binding for OpenGL shaders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4635913/explicit-vs-automatic-attribute-location-binding-for-opengl-shaders)
>   [Why should I use glBindAttribLocation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12051205/why-should-i-use-glbindattriblocation)

I tried to call glGetAttribLocation without binding any attrib locations and it seemed to work. So I can always cache the attrib locations in array if I want to have instant access. What is the purpose of using glBindAttribLocation then ?

[OpenGL 2.0]

Comment: See also [Explicit vs Automatic attribute location binding for OpenGL shaders](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4635913/explicit-vs-automatic-attribute-location-binding-for-opengl-shaders), which has a good discussion of this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`glBindAttribLocation` "binds" an index to an attribute name. This allows you to use the same indices for the same attributes across different shaders. For example: vertex coordinates = 0, texture coordinates = 1, normals = 2. This simplifies drawing code, by conforming the shader to your code, rather than the other way around (requesting attrib locations).

In my code I create an enum for common vertex attributes:

```
enum
{
    GRAPHICS_ATTRIB_VERTEX = 0,
    GRAPHICS_ATTRIB_NORMAL,
    GRAPHICS_ATTRIB_TEXTURE,
};
```

Bind them using `glBindAttribLocation`, then I can use them like this:

```
    glVertexAttribPointer(GRAPHICS_ATTRIB_VERTEX, ....);
```

This will work with all my shaders with no calls to `glGetAttribLocation`.