# Getting OpenGL Shader variables into C++ without writing a custom parser

Tags: c++, opengl

I couldn't find anything about this so here goes: What I'm trying to do is make a generic game engine, I want to be able to load any 3D object and apply any shader to that model.

I'm at the point where I need to know where the vertex attributes in the shader are so I can feed them to `glVertexAttribPointer`, However, `glVertexAttribPointer` takes as input the location of the attribute. 
Different shaders could have different locations for the vertices. Is there a way to query the attributes in a shader and store them in a list in c++?

*Post Answer: I've found the following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4635913/explicit-vs-automatic-attribute-location-binding-for-opengl-shaders/4638906#4638906) that explains it in more detail.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can query active shader attributes by using [`glGetActiveAttrib`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGetActiveAttrib.xhtml). In combination with [`glGetAttribLocation`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGetAttribLocation.xhtml), you can build up such a lookup table.

But even with this lookup table, you'd have to use a different VAO for each combination of mesh and shader. I suggest you go the other way round and define which attribute location belongs to which attribute. You can either enforce that with [`glBindAttribLocation`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glBindAttribLocation.xhtml) during shader compilation, or you use layout qualifiers ([`layout(location = ...)`](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Layout_Qualifier_(GLSL)#Vertex_shader_attribute_index)) in the shader. Using this, you will be able to use the same VAO with all of your shaders.