# glEnableClientState vs shader's attribute location

Tags: opengl, glsl

I can connect a VBO data with the shader's attribute using the followings functions:

```
GLint attribVertexPosition = glGetAttribLocation(progId, "vertexPosition");
glEnableVertexAttribArray(attribVertexPosition);
glVertexAttribPointer(attribVertexPosition, 3, GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
```

I analyze a legacy OpenGL code where a VBO is used with the following functions:

```
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);
```

How that legacy code makes a connnection between a VBO data and the shader's attribute:

```
attribute vec3 vertexPosition;
```

?

Comment: Isn't that fixed pipeline stuff? I think `glEnableClientState` predates shaders. Alternatively, due to some compat stuff, it's likely that it just binds in some predefined order...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For these fixed-function functions, the binding between the buffer and the vertex attribute is fixed. You don't tell `glVertexArray` which attribute it feeds; it *always* feeds the attribute `gl_Vertex`, which is defined for you in the shader. It cannot feed any user-defined attribute.

User-defined attributes are a separate set of attributes from the fixed-functioned ones.

Note that NVIDIA hardware is known to violate this rule. It [aliases certain attribute locations with certain built-in vertex arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/a/528824/734069), which allows user-defined attributes to receive data from fixed-function arrays. Perhaps you are looking at code that relies on this non-standard behavior that is only available on NVIDIA's implementation.

Comment: How it is fixed ? For example I can also call ```glEnableClientState( GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY );``` and  ```glTexCoordPointer```. Then the shader will contain ```attribute vec3 vertexPosition;``` and ```attribute vec2 vertexTexCoord;```. I know that is obsolete but I debug legacy OpenGL code.

Comment: Or maybe using a shader which defines attributes doesn't makes sense when a client code uses  ```glEnableClientState``` and ```glVertex/TexCoord/NormalPointer``` functions ?

Comment: @Irbis: "*How it is fixed ?*" By fiat. The standard specifically says which *pre-defined* vertex shader inputs are fed from these functions. `glTexCoordPointer` feeds one of the `gl_MultiTexCoord#` inputs, depending on the current `glActiveTexture` at the time of use.

Comment: @Irbis: I've added a note about old NVIDIA-specific functionality.